# Why can't my c++ lambda function be captured?

Tags: c++, lambda, c++11

Say I have a templated Action

```
template <class ArgT>
struct Action
{
    Action(::boost::function< void(ArgT) > func)
        : func_(func)
    {
    }

    void operator()(ArgT arg)
    {
        func_(arg);
    }

private:
        ::boost::function< void(ArgT) > func_;
};
```

I use Action like so :

```
class XCallbackInvoker : public CallbackInvoker< X >
{
public:
    XCallbackInvoker (Action< int > callback)
        : CallbackInvoker< X >(
            Action< ::boost::shared_ptr< X > >(
               [&callback](::boost::shared_ptr< X > x) -> void
               {
                   Action< int > callbackCopy = callback;
                   callbackCopy(x->errorCode());
               }))
    {
    }
};
```

Edit: CallbackInvoker added

```
template <class T>
class CallbackInvoker : public ICallbackInvoker
{
public:
    CallbackInvoker(Action< ::boost::shared_ptr< T > > callback)
        : callback_(callback)
    {
    }

    void invoke(::boost::shared_ptr< IBase > message)
    {
        callback_(::boost::static_pointer_cast< T >(message));
    }

private:
    Action< ::boost::shared_ptr< T > > callback_;
};
```

Now if I don't use a temporary to copy the value referenced by callback, it compiles fine but I get a runtime error (my callback is lost). If I pass my lambda the callback argument by value (that is `[=callback]`) and don't use the temporary, I get a compile error (my expression would lose some const-volatile qualifiers...)

Why can't I capture my lambda function by value instead of using a temporary?

Comment: Can you please also post the code for `CallbackInvoker<>` so we can try compiling this ourselves?

Comment: If you have a compiler error, it is usually better to copy that into the question, rather than condensing it into "my expression would loose some const-volatile qualifier". The error message was probably hinting at what particular use was triggering the problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you capture by copy then you cannot modify it by default, since the `operator()` of the lambda is declared `const`. You need to add `mutable` to your lambda to allow modifications of the captured variables:

```
XCallbackInvoker (Action< int > callback)
    : CallbackInvoker< X >(
        Action< ::boost::shared_ptr< X > >(
           [callback](::boost::shared_ptr< X > x) mutable -> void
           {
               callback(x->errorCode());
           }))
{
}
```

Comment: Thanks Anthony, I didn't know about the mutable trick on lambdas.

Comment: Or declare `operator()` of `struct Action` as `const`.

Comment: @Ben Voigt : Very likely the more appropriate solution.

Comment: @ildjarn: Still, both are worth mentioning.  I hadn't known @Anthony's trick either.